# Hive substring equivalent in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hive

I have rows of data in a file in the following manner:

```
0100234567   1234567     0000603842000000000000ABCDE               JOHN           J     01F19660129 2PO BOX 999
```

I have already inputed all the rows in the file in a pandas dataframe. Now what I need to do is that based on the positions of the characters, I need to separate out specific columns. In Hive, I could do a substring and output columns, but in pandas dataframe I am unable to do it.

For eg: In Hive, `NAME` could be `select substring(100,10) from temp;`

`100` is the position from where `NAME` of the person starts.

Is there something that I can do using the pandas dataframe? Any help would be appreciated. I have tried the str.slice but I think it is more specific to Series rather than dataframes.

Comment: If you say 'inputed al the rows in a file in a pandas dataframe' do you mean seperated each column, or just one column per row with the whole string in?

Comment: Just 1 column, with the entire string in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html), is possible use parameter `colspecs` or inherited with first 100 rows:

```
df = pd.read_fwf('filename')
```

For custom names is possible use:

```
df = pd.read_fwf('filename', names=list('abcdefghi'))
```

Better explanaion is in [Files with Fixed Width Columns](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#files-with-fixed-width-columns).

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""0100234567   1234567     0000603842000000000000ABCDE               JOHN           J     01F19660129 2PO BOX 999
0100234567   1234567     0000603842000000000000ABCDE               JOHN           J     01F19660129 2PO BOX 999
0100234567   1234567     0000603842000000000000ABCDE               JOHN           J     01F19660129 2PO BOX 999"""
```

```
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(temp), names=list('abcdefghi'))
print (df)

           a        b                            c     d  e            f    g  \
0  100234567  1234567  0000603842000000000000ABCDE  JOHN  J  01F19660129  2PO   
1  100234567  1234567  0000603842000000000000ABCDE  JOHN  J  01F19660129  2PO   
2  100234567  1234567  0000603842000000000000ABCDE  JOHN  J  01F19660129  2PO   

     h    i  
0  BOX  999  
1  BOX  999  
2  BOX  999  

print (type(df))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

But if need values only by positions use [indexing with .str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str), for `read_csv` need separator which is `not` in data like `|` or `¥`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""0100234567   1234567     0000603842000000000000ABCDE               JOHN           J     01F19660129 2PO BOX 999
0100234567   1234567     0000603842000000000000ABCDE               JOHN           J     01F19660129 2PO BOX 999
0100234567   1234567     0000603842000000000000ABCDE               JOHN           J     01F19660129 2PO BOX 999"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), names= ['col'], sep='|')
print (df)

                                                 col
0  0100234567   1234567     000060384200000000000...
1  0100234567   1234567     000060384200000000000...
2  0100234567   1234567     000060384200000000000...

df['a'] = df['col'].str[7:10]
df['b'] = df['col'].str[15:20]
df = df.drop('col', axis=1)
print (df)
     a      b
0  567  34567
1  567  34567
2  567  34567
```

Comment: Do I need to reassign the dataframe using read_fwf? I have already read it using read_csv. I know I am asking naive questions, but I am completely new to python.

Comment: Output of `read_fwf` is `DataFrame`, so no reaasign is necessary.

Comment: Okay. But I really cannot assign columns, since I have more than 100 columns. The method I am following is to input all the rows and the columns into 1 field and then substring only the necessary fields for the next steps.

Comment: Hmm, if use `read_fwf` with your real data, data are parsed correctly to columns? Or not?

Comment: This works perfectly @jezrael... Thank you so much! Should I just substring on each of the columns now to get specific output columns?

Comment: I think yes. you can use `names = ['col1','col2','col3']`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142643/discussion-between-manas-jani-and-jezrael).

Comment: I am unfortunately offline (only on phone rarely), if still problem maybe the best is post new question.